# использование rest php

Tags: php, apache

Добрый день, 
Прошу обьяснить как могу отправить вот такой запрос get или post?
ситуация:
- у меня на локалке развернут проект по адресу shop.localhost (виртуальный хост)
- я создал папку в корне сервера (localhost) файл rest.php
- c помощью post или get запроса нужно сделать запрос к shop.localhost
- отправить нужно запрос формата

```
http://shop.localhost/api/category-list/json/?login=LOGIN&password=PASSWORD
```

- и должен мне прийти ответ список категорий (LOGIN И PASSWORD нужный подставить)

вот что пробовал:

```
$url = 'http://shop.localhost/api/category-list/json/?';
$myvars = 'login=amin22&password=5e4cc507b79b211dc1102a0efadb083c';
$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $myvars);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec( $ch );
var_dump($response);// return -> false
```

подскажите пожалуйста как я могу проверить что действительно отправляю и отследить ошибки? спасибо

Comment: проб**о**вал​​​

Comment: В коде никаких косяков вроде не заметно. Попробуйте вывести ошибку - `var_dump(curl_error($ch));` после всего кода

Comment: "Failed to connect to shop.localhost port 80: Connection refused"  вот такой ответ, но через браузер могу зайти по этому адресу, из за чего такая ошибка?

Comment: Скрипт лежит тоже на локальной машине?

Comment: @DOC_tr  да.  Сайт находится по адресу /var/www/shop.localhost (виртуальный хост)  а файл со скриптом лежит /var/www/trysome/rest.php  при такой постановке работать должна эта конструкция?

Answer (score 1):

Советую вам проверить, что по имени shop.localhost действительно осуществляется переход на localhost. Ваше доменное имя может не ассоциироваться с localhost и из-за этого все проблемы.

Еще советую с браузера зайти по указанному вами адресу `http://shop.localhost/api/category-list/json/?login=LOGIN&password=PASSWORD` и посмотреть, что браузер думает по этому поводу.

Comment: выдает данные которые должны возвращатся {"0":{"id":"3","name":"\u041c\u0435\u0431\u0435\u043b\u044c","parentId":"0","image":false,"hidden":"0","sort":"0","level":0,"childsArray":[]},"1":{"id":"2","name":"\u041c\u043e\u0442\u043e\u0446\u0438\u043a\u043b\u044b","parentId":"0","image":false,"hidden":"0","sort":"0","level":0,"childsArray":[]},"2":{"id":"1","name":"\u0410\u0432\u0442\u043e\u043c\u043e\u0431\u0438\u043b\u0438","parentId":"0","image":false,"hidden":"0","sort":"1","level":0,"childsArray":[]},"result":"ok"}

Comment: попробуйте `file_get_contents()` раз у вас поддерживаются get запросы